# Labeling edges in GraphPlot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to animate the evolution of a discrete-time Markov chain, using the example on p. 30 of Kleinrock v. 1. This works pretty well:

```
p = {
 {0, 3/4, 1/4},
 {1/4, 0, 3/4},
 {1/4, 1/4, 1/2}
}
Animate[BarChart[{0, 1, 0}.MatrixPower[p, n], PlotRange -> 1, 
        ChartLabels -> {"Kyoto", "Tokyo", "Osaka"}, 
        Epilog -> {Text[Style[n, Bold, 14], 
        Scaled[{.05, .9}], {-1, 0}]}], {n, 0, 10, 1}, AnimationRate -> 1,
        AnimationRunning -> False, RefreshRate -> 30]
```

So next I want to draw the state graph itself...and I get stuck trying to put the labels on the vertices AND edges the way I want. This will label the vertices with the city name:

```
cities = {"Kyoto", "Tokyo", "Osaka"}
GraphPlot[p, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True,
          MultiedgeStyle -> All, SelfLoopStyle -> All, EdgeLabeling -> True,
          VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .1], 
          Black, Text[cities[[#2]], #1]} &)]
```

And this gives a less-pretty but serviceable view of the graph with the edge weights taken from the matrix:

```
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[p, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to combine the two.

Ultimately my plan is to draw a bar alongside the circle of the vertex, like the corresponding bar in the Animate above, so I really need some plot function that lets me modify the vertex rendering.  (I'm sure I'll be back with more questions about that later...)

fwiw, this is Mathematica 11.0.1.0 on a Mac.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`EdgeRenderingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeRenderingFunction.html) option of [`GraphPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot.html) to control the plot of the edges and add you the weights.

First you will need to transform `p` into the vertex-label syntax of `GraphPlot`.

```
vl = Flatten[MapIndexed[{Rule @@ #2, #1} &, p, {-1}], 1];
```

Then with the following `EdgeRenderingFunction` the weights will draw.

```
GraphPlot[vl,
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 MultiedgeStyle -> All,
 SelfLoopStyle -> All,
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (
   {Darker@Red, Arrow[#1, 0.1],
     Black,
     Inset[#3,
      With[{len = Length@#1},
       If[len == 2,
        Mean[#1],
        #1[[Ceiling[len/2]]]
        ]],
      Background -> White]} &),
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .1], 
     Black, Text[cities[[#2]], #1]} &)
 ]
```

[image]

You can [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) the `#3` parameter to make it more to your liking.

Hope this helps.

Also, check out [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) for a forum dedicated to Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks, that does it! But it's well beyond my Mathematica capabilities, I would never have gotten there. I don't grok about half of what you presented, so I have studying to do.

Comment: This comes pretty close to what I wanted, although even with the refresh rate set to 30, it blinks in ugly ways on my laptop. My laptop is well past retirement age, though.

Answer (score 0):

Combined with the above answer, this comes pretty close to what I wanted, although even with the refresh rate set to 30, it blinks in ugly ways on my laptop. My laptop is well past retirement age, though.

```
Animate[GraphPlot[vl, DirectedEdges -> True, MultiedgeStyle -> All, 
  SelfLoopStyle -> All, 
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Darker@Red, Arrow[#1, 0.1], Black, 
  Inset[#3, 
   With[{len = Length@#1}, 
    If[len == 2, Mean[#1], #1[[Ceiling[len/2]]]]], 
   Background -> White]} &),
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (
    {White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#1, 0.12],
    Pink, EdgeForm[Pink],
    {svpi = {0, 1, 0}.MatrixPower[p, n]; 
    Disk[#1, .1, {\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2 - 2 \[Pi] svpi[[#2]]}]},
    Black, Text[cities[[#2]], #1]} &)],
  {n, 0, 10, 1}, AnimationRate -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False, 
  RefreshRate -> 30]
```